# Slicing a dataframe with the ratio of a specific column (labels) remained

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
      var1                  var2                       label
 0    ".."                  ".."                        0
 1    ".."                  ".."                        0
 2    ".."                  ".."                        1
 3    ".."                  ".."                        0
 ...
 601  ".."                  ".."                        1
```

The ratio `1` and `0` in the column `label` are **0.6** and **0.4**, respectively.

How can I slice this data frame in such a way that the number of observations is now 30% of the total (601) but the ratio in `label` remained the same? For example:

```
      var1                  var2                       label
 0    ".."                  ".."                        1
 1    ".."                  ".."                        0
 2    ".."                  ".."                        0
 3    ".."                  ".."                        0
 ...
 181  ".."                  ".."                        0
```

with ratio `1` and `0` in `label` still being **0.6** and **0.4**, respectively.

I tried the following: `df = df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.3, random_state=1).reset_index(drop=True))`. This keeps the ratio of `label` indeed the same. However, it returns a weird index format:

```
             var1                      var2                       label
label               
0       0    ".."                      ".."                        0
        1    ".."                      ".."                        0
        2    ".."                      ".."                        0
        3    ".."                      ".."                        1
...
        181  ".."                      ".."                        1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is `groupby().head()`:

```
# number of sample per class
N = int(len(df)*0.2)//2

df.groupby('label').head(N)
```

If you want to randomly sample you can use `groupby().sample()` with pandas 1.1+:

```
df.groupby('label').sample(n=N)
```

Or you can shuffle the data before `groupby().head()`:

```
df.sample(frac=1).groupby('label').head(N)
```

---

**Update** if you mean you want to keep the ratio of the labels as `0.6:0.4`, then `groupby().sample()` would give you close to that original ratio:

```
df.groupby('label').sample(frac=0.2)
```

Comment: @jxpython  move `reset_index(drop=True)` outside of `groupby().apply()`.

Comment: The labels are now ordered. They first begin with 0. You got an explanation for this?

Comment: Because `groupby` would sort the keys by default. Pass `sort=False` to `groupby()` to keep the original order.

Comment: Would have made sense but unfortunately did not avoid it. It still begints with 0. Here is the line I'm using: df = df.groupby('label', sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.3, random_state=1)).reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Try `sort_index` before drop: `(df.groupby('label').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.3))
   .sort_index(level=1)
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)`

Comment: You are a legend man. You made my day. Thank you.